# Bind function to dynamically created element

Tags: c#, wpf

Just a quick question.
I am working on WPF Project (using c#).

So I Have a function, which on click of a radnom listview item shows it's text in textbox.

```
private void show_it(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)sender;
        textBox1.Text = item.Content.ToString();

    }
```

Now, If I create another Listview item in c#, I can't find a way to bind this same function to that newly created element.

```
        ListViewItem new_i=new ListViewItem();
        new_i.Content = "test";
        /* Tried; not working:
        new_i.SetValue(OnMouseLeftButtonUp, "show_it");
         */
        listView1.Items.Add(new_i);
```

How can I implement this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you use proper DataBinding as opposed to creating and manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that you need to delete all this code and create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding to populate the UI as opposed to `listview1.Items.Add()` type of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routed event handlers in WPF are programmatically assigned the same way as other .Net events.

```
ListViewItem new_i=new ListViewItem();
new_i.Content = "test";
new_i.Click += show_it;

listView1.Items.Add(new_i);
```

When you have time, I would recommend that you read up on data binding in WPF.

Comment: It's working, but with new_i.MouseLeftButtonUp :D
I will take your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

In XAML register a handler:

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
```

In code behind:

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ListView control = (ListView)sender;
  var item = (ListViewItem)control.SelectedItem;
  textBox1.Text = item.Content.ToString();
}
```

But as HighCore said, DataBinding is the much better solution